# Mistery margin around Picturebox and label

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, picturebox

I've built a little usercontrol, useful for displaying datagrid with title and datetime.

Unfortunately, as I add it to another parent control, I see there's space wrapping labels and pictureBox.

See it here: [userControl design and execution are different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4RZW.png)

```
// 
// pictureBox_Resize
// 
this.pictureBox_Resize.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.pictureBox_Resize.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.pictureBox_Resize.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeNWSE;
this.pictureBox_Resize.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox_Resize.Image")));
this.pictureBox_Resize.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(315, 165);
this.pictureBox_Resize.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.pictureBox_Resize.Name = "pictureBox_Resize";
this.pictureBox_Resize.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(16, 16);
this.pictureBox_Resize.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.pictureBox_Resize.TabIndex = 2;
this.pictureBox_Resize.TabStop = false;
this.pictureBox_Resize.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox_Resize_MouseDown);
this.pictureBox_Resize.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox_Resize_MouseMove);
this.pictureBox_Resize.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox_Resize_MouseUp);
// 
// panel1
// 
this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.AppWorkspace;
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox_Resize);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.panel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(331, 181);
this.panel1.TabIndex = 3;
this.panel1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.panel1_MouseDown);
this.panel1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.panel1_MouseMove);
this.panel1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.panel1_MouseUp);
// 
// panel2
// 
this.panel2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.lblQueryTitle);
this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox_Reload);
this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.lblQueryLastRun);
this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox_Run);
this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.panel2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(331, 20);
this.panel2.TabIndex = 7;
// 
// lblQueryTitle
// 
this.lblQueryTitle.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
this.lblQueryTitle.AutoSize = true;
this.lblQueryTitle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
this.lblQueryTitle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.lblQueryTitle.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 2);
this.lblQueryTitle.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.lblQueryTitle.Name = "lblQueryTitle";
this.lblQueryTitle.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 18);
this.lblQueryTitle.TabIndex = 1;
this.lblQueryTitle.Text = "label1";
// 
// lblQueryLastRun
// 
this.lblQueryLastRun.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
this.lblQueryLastRun.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
this.lblQueryLastRun.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.lblQueryLastRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(267, 2);
this.lblQueryLastRun.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.lblQueryLastRun.Name = "lblQueryLastRun";
this.lblQueryLastRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 18);
this.lblQueryLastRun.TabIndex = 5;
this.lblQueryLastRun.Text = "03:40:59";
// 
// pictureBox_Run
// 
this.pictureBox_Run.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.pictureBox_Run.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
this.pictureBox_Run.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox_Run.Image")));
this.pictureBox_Run.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(251, 2);
this.pictureBox_Run.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.pictureBox_Run.Name = "pictureBox_Run";
this.pictureBox_Run.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(16, 16);
this.pictureBox_Run.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.pictureBox_Run.TabIndex = 4;
this.pictureBox_Run.TabStop = false;
this.pictureBox_Run.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_Run_Click);
// 
// dataGridView1
// 
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip11;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridViewCellStyle2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 20);
this.dataGridView1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F);
dataGridViewCellStyle3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle3;
this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(331, 161);
this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
// 
// CustomDataGrid2
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
this.Name = "CustomDataGrid2";
this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(331, 181);
this.contextMenuStrip11.ResumeLayout(false);
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox_Resize)).EndInit();
this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
this.panel1.PerformLayout();
this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
this.panel2.PerformLayout();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox_Reload)).EndInit();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox_Run)).EndInit();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

I've already set `Padding:0, Margin: 0` for everything in my little usercontrol.

And I also set anchor for elements 1,2,3,4:

1. `anchor: top, left;`
2. `anchor: top, right;`
3. `anchor: top, right;`
4. `anchor: bottom, right;`

I've also tried setting autosize on labels, but result doesn't change: label/picturebox won't anchor to the limit of the parent panel, as seen in designer! there's still that mistery margin :(

Comment: Lay out your controls in a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) and set a proper `SizeType` of each row and column. The TLP extends its controls and provides properties `Cell`, `Column`, `ColumnSpan`, `Row`, `RowSpan` ... Select a control and switch to the Properties window to set these properties as you need.